# Phalcon Fatal Error on hasMany Relationship

Tags: orm, model, entity-relationship, phalcon, has-many

I have this ERD below:

[image]

> Relations are as follow, 
>   Entity to Host is One to One 
>   Host to Portal is One to Many ( One Host to Many Portal )

```
class Entity extends Model
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasOne(
            "entity_id",
            "Host",
            "entity_id"
        );
    }
}

class Host extends Model
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->belongsTo(
            "entity_id",
            "Host",
            "entity_id"
        );
        $this->hasMany(
            "host_id"
            "Portal",
            "host_id"
        );
    }
}
class Portal extends Model
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->belongsTo(
            "portal_id",
            "Host,
            "portal_id"
        );
    }
}
```

When i try to retrieve the list of Portals base on the array of entity id provided, i got a fatal error.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple::getHost()

This is my controller code to retrieve the portals

```
$hostObj = Host::find(['entity_id IN ({ids:array})',
             'bind' => array('ids' => $entity_id)]);

if($hostObj)
{
    $portals = $hostObj->Portal;
}
```

Basically the goal is to retrieve the list of Portals base on the array of entity_id provided. But i really wonder, whats wrong with my model relations that lead into the fatal error.

Comment: Where are you using `getHost()` ?

Answer (score -1):

Find method returns Resultset, you need either to use `findFirst` or select row from `Resultset`(like array-like style `$portals[0]`, or `$portals->getFirst()` or `$portals->offsetGet('0')`

Comment: Isn't it findFirst, will fetch only the first row found? It wouldn't work because I need the list of Portals base on the entity_id

Comment: Confirmed it, firstFirst will only fetch the first row found. It won't fetch all rows found.

Comment: Then it wont work like this. $hostObj is resultset. You need to select row from it. You need to use query builder to do want you want most likely. Despite of that your relation are wrong. Check docs. BelongsTo first argument is field in current model, second is related class, third is field in **related model**. For hasMany it's the same.

I don't see `portal_id` field in Host.